# Force Close problem while Moving track ball on disabled EditText On HTC Hero Phone?

Tags: android, android-activity

i have a small form with

four EditText fields in which second EditText is disable for text Editing.

now when i roll Android Phone ball to move from the top to bottom first time it selects disabled EditText and then third EditText and moves downward to foruth EditText.

but when i try to move upward  on Disabled EditText it displays me error Force Close after selecting it.

it is only happening in phone not in Emulator.

please guide how to resolve this issue?

any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: no i cant because this problem does not appear in emulator only in HTC hero phone. never tested any other phone yet.

Comment: is there any on scroll like event exists in EditText?

Comment: You can still post a stack trace if it happened on a phone...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when i move track ball up and down after getting focus on disabled Edittext second time i receive Force close problem in HTC hero only.

i have tested same problem on Nexus one phone nothing happened.

anyways in HTC Hero i have found solution just setting Disabled Editext selection to false.